# Не проходит POST запрос на клиенте JS React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post

У меня есть контроллер, который добавляет в БД вопрос и ответы к нему, проверяю в Postman, контроллер работает, все ок, вот сам код контроллера:

```
async create(req, res, next) {
    // создание вопроса

    try {
      const { text, testId, answerList } = req.body;
      let fileName;
  
      if (req.files) {
        const { image } = req.files;
        fileName = uuid.v4() + ".jpg";
        image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'static', fileName));
      }
  
      const question = await Question.create({
        text,
        image: fileName || null,
        testId,
      });
  
      const answerIds = [];
  
      for (let i = 0; i < answerList.length; i++) {
        const text = answerList[i];
        const isCorrect = i === 0;
        const answer = await Answer.create({ text, correct: isCorrect, questionId: question.id });
        answerIds.push(answer.id);
      }
  
      await question.update({ answerList: answerIds });
      const count = await Question.count({ where: { testId } });
      const test = await Test.findByPk(testId);
      await test.update({ questionCount: count });
  
      return res.json({ question, answers: answerIds });
    } catch (e) {
      next(ApiError.badRequest(e.message));
    }
  }
```

Запрос в постман Body:

```
{
  "text": "Пожалуйста работай",
  "testId": 18,
  "answerList": ["это", "должно", "работать"]
}
```

и ответ сервера:

```
{
    "question": {
        "type": "CLOSE",
        "id": 17,
        "text": "Пожалуйста работай",
        "image": null,
        "testId": 18,
        "updatedAt": "2023-05-11T13:12:59.238Z",
        "createdAt": "2023-05-11T13:12:59.088Z",
        "answerList": [
            93,
            94,
            95
        ]
    },
    "answers": [
        93,
        94,
        95
    ]
}
```

Теперь я пытаюсь реализовать этот метод на клиенте, добавить в модальное окно, которое добавляет вопрос и ответы к нему, но происходит ошибка `tp://localhost:5000/api/question 404 (Not Found)`, путь запроса точно правильный, и еще ошибка в разделе Сеть:`"notNull Violation: question.text cannot be null"`
Апи для создания вопроса:

```
export const createQuestion = async (question) => {
    const {data} = await $authHost.post('api/question', {question})
    return data
};
```

И код самого компонента, где я вывожу данные в консоль, чтобы понять причину:

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import React, {  useState } from "react";
import { Modal, Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { createQuestion } from "../../http/questionAPI";

const CreQuestion = observer(({ show, onHide, testId }) => {

  const[text, setText] =useState('');
  const[file, setFile] =useState(null);
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]); // состояние для ответов

  const handleAddAnswer = () => {// функция добавления нового ответа в массив
    setAnswers([...answers, { id: answers.length, text: "" }]);
  };

  const handleRemoveAnswer = (id) => {// функция удаления ответа по его id
    setAnswers(answers.filter((a) => a.id !== id));
  };

  const handleAnswerChange = (id, text) => {// функция обновления текста ответа по его id
    let newAnswers = [...answers];
    newAnswers[id] = { ...newAnswers[id], text};
    setAnswers(newAnswers);
  };

  const selectFile = e => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0])
  }


  const AddQuestion = () => { //функция для создания вопроса 

    const formData = new FormData()
    console.log("Text:", text);
    console.log("File:", file);
    console.log("Test ID:", testId);
   
    formData.append('text', text)
    formData.append('image', file)
    formData.append('testId', testId) 
    console.log("Answers:", answers);
    formData.append('answerList', JSON.stringify(answers));

    createQuestion(formData).then((data)=> {
      onHide();
    })
  }

  return (
    <Modal show={show}
    onHide={onHide} centered>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
          Редактирование вопроса
        </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <Form>
          <Form.Control 
          value={text}
          onChange={e=> setText(e.target.value)}
          className="mt-3"  
          placeholder={"Введите текст вопроса"} 
          />
          <Form.Control 
          className="mt-3" 
          type="file"
          onChange={selectFile}
          />


          {answers.map((answer) => (
            <div key={answer.id} style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" , justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
              <Form.Control
                className="mt-3 mr-3"
                placeholder={`Введите ответ ${answer.id + 1}`}
                value={answer.text}
                onChange={(e) => handleAnswerChange(answer.id, e.target.value)} style={{ marginRight: "10px" }}
              />
              <Button className="mt-3" variant={"outline-danger"} onClick={() => handleRemoveAnswer(answer.id)}>Удалить</Button>
            </div>
          ))}
        <hr/>
        </Form>
        <Button variant={"outline-primary"} onClick={handleAddAnswer}>Добавить ответ</Button>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="outline-danger" onClick={onHide}>
          Закрыть
        </Button>
        <Button variant="outline-success" onClick={AddQuestion}>
          Сохранить
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
});

export default CreQuestion;
```

и консоль выводит данные, которые я ввожу в модальном окне, поэтому и не понимаю причины ошибки:

[image: вывод консоли]

Comment: может Answers логичнее выводить внутри createQuestion().then(...)? ну а ошибка 404 так трудно сказать почему (может не тот тип запроса get вместо post, или url неверный, попробовать слеш в конце поставить). notNull violation скорей всего на стороне сохранения в БД происходит, можно в контроллер логирование добавить тоже.